# If $u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^1{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ may I suppose that $|u(x)|=\frac{1}{\omega_n} \int_{B_{1}(x)}|u(x)|dy?$ How to prove it?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-functions

If $u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^1{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ and $\omega_n$ is the volume of a ball, may I always suppose that
$$|u(x)|=\frac{1}{\omega_n} \int_{B_{1}(x)}|u(x)|dy?$$

How to prove it?
I thought this equality was only possible if $u$ was a harmonic function. But now, how can I be sure of this equality? or am I making a confusion about the mean value property?
Because there is a result that a function satisfies the mean value property iff is harmonic.

My attempt:

We know that the volume of $B_1(x)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is ${\omega_n}=\int_{B_{1}(x)}dy$, so if I replace in the equality above may I take $|u(x)|$ out of the integral, even if the center of the ball is $x$? I mean, can I do this:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\omega_n} \int_{B_{1}(x)}|u(x)|dy&= \frac{1}{\int_{B_{1}(x)}dy} \int_{B_{1}(x)}|u(x)|dy\\
& =\frac{\int_{B_1(x)} dy}{\int_{B_1(x)}dy} |u(x)|\\
&=|u(x)|
\end{align*}

?????????

Comment: This is true, since the integrand is $\lvert u(x) \rvert$ instead of $\lvert u(y) \rvert$. If you mean $\lvert u(y) \rvert$, then it is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Meowdog but, how to prove this equality?  I really mean $|u(x)|$ Sorry if it is an elementary question, but I didn't understand.

Comment: You can just take the integrand $\vert u(x) \vert$ out of the integral, since you integrate over $y$ and not $x$. Then, by translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure, the measure of $B_1(x)$ is the same as $B_1(0)$, which is $\omega_n$, so you're done.

Comment: @stange thanks very much. One little thing please: is true that $\int_{B_{r}(x)} dy = \int_{x}^{r} dy$?

Comment: No, that is not true. In multiple dimensions, the right-hand side wouldn't even make sense. And even if you're in 1D, then the right-hand side would read $\int_{x-r}^{x+r} dy$.

Comment: @stange Perfect, thanks for answering this elementary doubt.